# If function and derivative extend continuously to boundary of domain, can one extend as $C^1$ function?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, connected, bounded. Let $f : D \to \mathbb{R}$ be $C^1$ and assume that $f$ as well as $\partial_i f$ extend as continuous functions to the closure $\overline{D}$ of $D$ for all $i \in \{1, \ldots, n\}$.

The paper [Functions Differentiable on the Boundaries of Regions](https://doi.org/10.2307/1968745) by Whitney shows in particular that if $D$ is quasi-convex (Property P in the paper) then one can extend $f$ as a $C^1$ function to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I would guess this fails if one does not make a suitable assumption like quasi-convexity on the domain $D$ — does anyone know a good counterexample?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The failure is essentially local, so the boundedness we can ignore for the purpose of this example.

- Let $D = \{ y < |x|^{1/4}: (x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2\}$.
- Let $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $\phi(y) = 0$ for $y \leq 0$ and $\phi(y) = y^2$ for $y > 0$.
- Let $f:D\to \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(x,y) = \mathrm{sign}(x) \phi(y)$.

We have $\partial_x f \equiv 0$ and
$$
\partial_y f = 
\begin{cases} 
0 & y \leq 0 \\ 
2\mathrm{sign}(x) y & y > 0
\end{cases}.
$$ It is not too hard to see that $f$ and its first derivatives have continuous extensions to $\bar{D}$.

Fixing $y >0$, applying the mean value theorem to $x\mapsto f(x,y)$, we see that any putative differentiable extension will require there having a point with $|x| \leq y^4$ that satisfy $\partial_x f(x,y) = y^{-2}$. This shows it is impossible to have a $C^1$ extension to all $\mathbb{R}^2$ as the continuous extension of $\partial_x f(0,0) = 0$.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice and clear counterexample.